# How Can I simplify this SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query below...  these are input filter ($P{start_date}) however It is currently giving me an error in Jaspersoft Studio.

I have discovered that the problem might be with my FROM criteria. I have used JOIN instead of INNER JOIN but it does not return any results.

I would like to know if there is any way to simplify this query.

```
SELECT
LOCATIONS.ID AS LOCATIONID,
LOCATIONS.NAME AS LOCATIONNAME,
PRODUCTS.REFERENCE,
PRODUCTS.CODE AS BARCODE,
PRODUCTS.NAME AS ITEM_NAME,
STOCKDIARY.ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID,
ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE.DESCRIPTION AS ATTINSTANCEDESC,
PRODUCTS.CATEGORY,
TICKETLINES.UNITS,
CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORYNAME,
STOCKDIARY.DATENEW,
STOCKDIARY.REASON,
SUM(CASE WHEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS <0 AND STOCKDIARY.DATENEW >=  $P{start_date} AND (STOCKDIARY.DATENEW) <= $P{end_date} THEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS ELSE 0 END) AS UNITSOUT,
SUM(CASE WHEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS >=0 AND STOCKDIARY.DATENEW >=  $P{start_date} AND (STOCKDIARY.DATENEW) <= $P{end_date} THEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS ELSE 0 END) AS UNITSIN,
SUM(CASE WHEN STOCKDIARY.DATENEW <= $P{end_date} THEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS ELSE 0 END) AS STOCKTOTALNEW,
SUM(CASE WHEN STOCKDIARY.DATENEW <=  $P{start_date} THEN STOCKDIARY.UNITS ELSE 0 END) AS STARTINGBALANCE,
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNIT


FROM TICKETLINES,
STOCKDIARY
LEFT JOIN
LOCATIONS ON STOCKDIARY.LOCATION = LOCATIONS.ID
INNER JOIN
PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.ID = STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
LEFT JOIN
CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID
LEFT JOIN
ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE ON STOCKDIARY.ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID  = ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE.ID


WHERE products.name LIKE "%"

GROUP BY LOCATIONS.NAME , PRODUCTS.REFERENCE , STOCKDIARY.ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID , ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY PRODUCTS.NAME
```

Comment: If possible, how about use procedure?

Comment: If you need to get the data on 5table, well you need to do some joins. I have queries that use 10+ tables without any performance issues. Remember to add index if needed. Edit : For the error ... well you need to give use a [mcve]

Comment: Readability: If possible, avoid having everything in CAPS. Works great for syntax keywords, but having everything in caps makes me kinda dizzy just looking at this.